# Printing empty brackets?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a simple program that should take two arrays, convert them into lists, and take out the values that are the same. For some reason though I am getting a value of:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Although the result should be "eggs", "lasers", "hats", "pie" - "lasers", "hats" which should get me a result of "eggs" "pie".

Here is my code:

```
public class Arraystring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] things = { "eggs", "lasers", "hats", "pie" };
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String x : things) { 
            list1.add(x);
        }
        String[] thingstwo = { "lasers", "hats" };
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
            list2.add(thingstwo[i]);
        }
        editlist(list1, list2);
    }

    public static void editlist(Collection<String> l1, Collection<String> l2) {

        Iterator<String> it = l1.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (l2.contains(it.next())) {
                System.out.println("hui");
                it.remove();
            }
            System.out.println(l2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `list2.size()` in that second `for` loop?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {  list2.add(thingstwo[i]); }` try to describe what happens in this code.

Comment: @Sotiros Delimanolis You are right, I meant to have this:

Comment: @Pshemo for(String i : thingstwo) 
 
 {
  list2.add(i);
  
 }

Comment: And there you have solution to your problem :)

Comment: @Pshemo But now with this, a new issue comes up. My output is [lasers, hats]. I have two questions, why is the [] there in lasers, hats? Also, Shouldn't the output be everything **except** [lasers, hats], shouldn't it be "eggs" "pie"? Thank you so much for all the help you provided, I appreciate it greatly! :)

Comment: In `editlist` method: from which collection you are removing items and which collection you are printing? Also are you sure that you want to print it inside your loop?

Comment: @Pshemo The code works when doing System.out.println(l1); , but I really want to learn **how it works**;  what is going on  in the code at  the .remove(). Is it removing a value from the iterator itself...? I fail to see where I am removing the items from l2, although that is what the code reflects. Please explain. BTW: Thanks, you are helping a fellow programmer out a lot!

Comment: @Pshemo Also, I did move the printing outside the loop.

Comment: "*I fail to see where I am removing the items from `l2`*" well, that is probably because you are not removing items from `l2`, you are removing them only from `l1` via `it.remove();`. Your loop uses iterator `it` to iterate over all elements in `l1` (since this iterator was created by `l1`). Now `if (l2.contains(it.next()))` tests if `l2` contains element returned by iterator, and if it does (when `contains` returns `true`) you are executing `it.remove();` which via `it` removes from `l1` item which iterator returned with `next()`.

Comment: @Pshemo I guess the part that I was confused on was the fact that since the iterator was created by l1, by removing the iterator (which i'm assuming is an instance of l1) you are removing parts of l1, right? If so, then this makes a lot of sense now! Thank you so much for that great explanation :) What I still don't understand is why the output is inside of square brackets ([ ])...? Thanks1

Comment: @Rich In editlist(), instead of iterating over l1 and checking whether l2 contains current element or not, you could have simply use the method removeAll. `l1.removeAll(l2);`

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't know that, thanks Sandeep! I have liked your comment. What I still don't understand is why the output is inside of square brackets ([ ]), instead of just plain text in the console though. Again, thanks for the help1

Comment: Take a look at `toString` method. It is used by `System.out.println` and in case of collections it generates String with its elements in a form `[element0, ..., elementN]`. But because of `i < list2.size();` condition you didn't place anything in `l2` so as result you printed `[]`.

Comment: @Pshemo Wow, that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks! I have liked your comment also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your line in Arraystring {..}

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
```

should be

```
    for (int i = 0; i < thingstwo.length; i++) {
```

And then you are printing the wrong list in editlist(..):

```
        System.out.println(l2);
```

should be

```
        System.out.println(l1);
```